# Sending string of text from iPhone to PC

Tags: objective-c, networking

All I need to do is when I press a button on my app, a string of text (eg. "text1"), to my PC where my VB.NET application can interpret it. Can this be done in a simple way? Pretty much if I could get my iPhone app to store data on a webpage for 30 seconds my VB.NET application could then take that data.

Cheers!

PS: Before down-voting this, please comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a service similar to [Parse](https://parse.com/docs/index), your iPhone app can send data to their servers for free (so long as you not making too many requests) and then your VB.Net program can pull the data. They have SDK's for iOS and .Net

Comment: Thank you so much, Parse.com seems like a dream website! I cannot comprehend how much I wish to thank you.